# Getting the exact strings of states/provinces that CLGeocoder returns

Tags: iphone, objective-c, clgeocoder

Where can I find the list of states and provinces that CLGeocoder returns when reverse-geocoding? There must be a list that defines and translates a set of coordinates into city/state/country/etc.
I am asking because I need to make sure there are no discrepancies between the strings CLGeocoder returns and the hard-coded ones in my application (especially since objective-c is case-sensitive). For example, is it "Newfoundland and Labrador" or "Newfoundland And Labrador" or "Newfoundland/Labrador" or something else?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Follow this [link](http://englishplus.com/grammar/00000057.htm) for a complete list of states and provinces. And by the way, it's "Newfoundland and Labrador". Hope that helps!